# Display JSF2 messages depending on the user language, not on to the JVM?

Tags: validation, jsf, internationalization

I'm using JSF2, I have a registration form. User can switch the language (English...).
I manage different languages by using resource-bundle in the configuration file faces-config.xml. So far so good.

Here a part of the registration form:

```
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.RegistrationLabel_email}" for="username" />
                        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{registrationController.current.username}" label="#{bundle.RegistrationTitle_email}" title="#{bundle.RegistrationTitle_email}" size="40" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateUserRequiredMessage_username}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
                            <f:validateLength maximum="60" />
                        </h:inputText>
```

I use a JSF2 validator, to validate the input size, it is a JSF2 feature:

```
    <f:validateLength maximum="60" />
```

If the size is greater than 60, it will display an error message to the user, in this case the language of the message is depending on the JVM.

I'd like that JSF2, displays its messages according to the user language but not on the JVM.

How to manage the JSF2 messages regardless the JVM?

Comment: How are you managing/switching languages then? Via `<f:view locale>`, right?

Comment: No,there is a file for each language, e.g. Bundle_en.properties for English... JSF2 detect the the right one.